# Help with Image Source replacement using jCarousel

Tags: jquery, image, jcarousel, replace

I'm trying create a image gallery for my website incorporating the Jcarousel plugin.

The general idea is that i have the carousel with thumbnails in a div below a div which is there for the full size image.

I have tested that when i click an image it returns a alert box (showing me that its registering a click) but as of yet all the snippets on the net ive seen haven't worked in replacing the image in the about div with its fullsize copy.

has anyone got an idea of how i can achieve this?

Main image is in a div called "imagebox"

The List for Jcarousel is an ID called mycarousel inside a div called scrollbox

so when one of the images in mycarousel is clicked, the image in imagebox will be replaced with a file of the same name with _l at the end of the file name (but obviously larger size)

any help will be appreciated.

all i ahve working at the moment is :

$('#mycarousel1 li img').live('click', function() {
             alert("clicked") 
    });

**to test if the click oin the carousel works**

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that adds a gallery type functionality to the jCarousel plugin: http://www.queness.com/post/3036/create-a-custom-jquery-image-gallery-with-jcarousel